# Adding Debian 9.9 to existing RHEL 8.0 system

Tags: debian, rhel, system-installation, dual-boot

I have a system with RHEL 8.0.  I need to install Debian 9.9 and make the system dual-bootable.  Would be grateful for any insight on how to do this especially if it includes specific steps.  A second disk will be added for the Debian installation.

(I was hoping that I could somehow add Debian without blowing away RHEL)

Comment: Debian has online User manuals that may help you. Take a look at: https://www.debian.org/doc/user-manuals

Comment: Thanks I did check there.  It is sprinkled with references to dual-booting but I was hoping for more directions for how to do it.  Maybe I missed something?  Will keep digging...

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DualBoot

Comment: Thanks, I did go there but it talks about dual boot with linux and Windows and I need to dual boot with 2 linux distros